# In Diablo 3, what should be the primary focus of a Lvl 675 paragon with 100+ hours played?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-necromancer

Been playing D3 since it originally came out, and I'm stuck in a bit of a skill rut. Here's what my typical session looks like on my necro:

1. grind bounties for essences and NR for fragments
2. grind GRs for gems, XP, shards, legendaries
3. Level up legendary gems to eventually 100~150 and enchant set armor
4. Hope for primal drops
5. Repeat

The cost to buff armor by sacrificing gems is crazy expensive (9 top-tier gems + lvl150 legendary). And I've only had one primal drop ever.

I've heard at this level paragon is a grind, but am I missing anything, or is this the end-game grind?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is all this game has to offer. Rifts, adventure mode, Paragon levels, and Primal gear are the "Top Level" things you can do in the game. Once you've done all of that, you've done it all.

The main reason that Primal drops are so rare, and take so long to grind is just so that you have something to do, while you keep playing the game. Other than that, play with friends, start a different character, maybe do a "Hardcore" run.